# Can sms-enabled UK and US Twilio numbers receive messages from Alphanumeric sender IDs?

Tags: twilio

I noticed that Twilio numbers are not receiving sms messages from alphanumeric senders. Is it possible to enable this feature for Twilio numbers in the UK and US?

If not, is there a legitimate workaround?

I tested with different numbers and couldn't get them to receive sms from alphanumeric IDs.

Comment: According to this [doc](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) Alphanumeric Sender IDs are not supported in the US. And regarding the UK, who is sending the SMS in this case? Are you trying to send it to yourself from the same Twilio account?

Answer (score 0):

- UK numbers can receive messages from an alphanumeric sender ID without any additional set up.
- US numbers cannot received messages from an alphanumeric sender ID.

[List](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID) of countries and whether they support receiving messages from the alphanumeric senders.